# What are the elements of the dihedral group D(3)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $D_3=\big<a,b| a^3=b^2=(ab)^2=1\big>$ and $|D_3|=6  $

$D_3=\{
 1, a, a^2, b, ab, a^2b\} $

Are these correct?

Then so that I can compute the orders of all the elements of the group $D_3$

Comment: Are you sure that they exist?

Comment: You mean the elements of $D_3$ that I wrote? @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: Leyla, I mean the element of order $6$.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it now @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: If so you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your title reads 'What are the elements of the dihedral group $D_3$ (which has order $6$)?', rather than 'what are the order $6$ elements in $D_3$'.

Then you must be careful. Your presentation reads $\langle a,b\mid a^3=b^2=1,(ab)^2=1\rangle$, so $a^3=1$, and so your $6$ elements are not correct. One idea here is to consider elements that you do know are in the group, and then use the group axioms to work out the rest (of the representatives, up to relations). It's clear that $\{1,a,a^2,b\}\subset D_3$.

Then you can consider the closure axiom. Each of these multiplied by $a$, $a^2$ and $b$ must still be in the group. So consider the elements $a^2,a^3,ab$. The first is already in our, the second is the identity and hence is already in our set, and the third wasn't, so let us now consider $\{1,a,a^2,b,ab\}$ what about multiplying by $b$ now? $b,ab,a^2b,b^2,ab^2$ all of these are in our group but for $a^2b$. So you have $\{1,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b\}\subseteq D_3$.

Then what are the orders? $a^3=1, (a^2)^3=1,b^2=1,(ab)^2=1,(a^2b)^2=1$.

$$(a^2b)^2=a^2ba^2b=aabaab=a(abab)b^{-1}ab=ab^{-1}ab=abab=1$$

Comment: I was suppposed to state that $D_3$ has order 6, but the use of language mixed it a little bit

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Yep, so if you follow my answer, you can find all of the correct elements

Comment: "One idea is to consider elements that you know are in the group, and then use the group axioms to work out the rest." I cannot make sense of this. Since a group defined by generators and relation is really a quotient of the free group $F$ on the generators, and when we write $ab$, for instance, we mean "the equivalence class of $ab\in F$ under this quotient", the elements we "know are in the group" are all possible strings involving $a$, $b$, and exponents, and the empty string. That doesn't seem like a very good place to start.

Comment: @JohnHughes Of course you cannot find the order easily from a group presentation, and really one asks for a 'better' definition of the dihedral group, say $\Bbb Z_n \rtimes \Bbb Z_2$. What I had written is better motivated if you look at the question history. Where what I am writing is mainly motivated from. They had written $D_3=\{1,a,a^2,a^3,b,ab\}$

Answer (score 1):

$<1>=1$, $<a>=<a^2>=3$, $<b>=<ab>=<ba^2>=2$.

$$(ba^2)^2=ba^2ba^2=ba(abab)ba=baba=b(abab)b=b^2=1.$$

Comment: If $\big< ba^2\big>=2 $ then $ ba^2ba^2=1$ $\iff baabaa=1$ $\iff bab^{-1}a^{-1}aa=1$ $\iff bab^{-1}a=1$ $\iff a^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}a=1$ $\iff a^{-1}b^{-2}a=1$  but I can't get that. How to show that $ ba^2ba^2=1$

Comment: @LeylaAlkan See my edit

Comment: Leyla, I added something.

Comment: I saw it, thanks! @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!